# How to update JSON on the API android

Tags: android, android-json

I am creating an app to update the JSON data on the API url

[image: n the API]

I want to add a new array item in the JSON ARRAY from the android app

Is it possible to do it and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. as long as you have controls on your backend which is the JSON API diagram you have there. Basically an ASYNC and AWAIT ( in reference to JAVASCRIPT )

but for android, saw this link
[android waiting for response from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229204/android-waiting-for-response-from-server)

Comment: What are the commands to set the JSON Array on the API? This link is to get the json data.I want to update the json data onto the API that have json data