# notifyDataSetChanged not working on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I am getting data from server and then parsing it and storing it in a List. I am using this list for the RecyclerView's adapter. I am using Fragments.

I am using a Nexus 5 with KitKat. I am using support library for this. Will this make a difference?

Here is my code: (Using dummy data for the question)

Member Variables:

```
List<Business> mBusinesses = new ArrayList<Business>();

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
BusinessAdapter mBusinessAdapter;
```

My `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Getting data from server
    getBusinessesDataFromServer();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business_list,
            container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.business_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mBusinessAdapter = new BusinessAdapter(mBusinesses);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mBusinessAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

After getting data from server, `parseResponse()` is called.

```
protected void parseResponse(JSONArray response, String url) {
    // insert dummy data for demo

    mBusinesses.clear();

    Business business;

    business = new Business();
    business.setName("Google");
    business.setDescription("Google HeadQuaters");
    mBusinesses.add(business);

    business = new Business();
    business.setName("Yahoo");
    business.setDescription("Yahoo HeadQuaters");
    mBusinesses.add(business);

    business = new Business();
    business.setName("Microsoft");
    business.setDescription("Microsoft HeadQuaters");
    mBusinesses.add(business);

    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Dummy Data Inserted\nBusinesses Length: "
            + mBusinesses.size());

    mBusinessAdapter = new BusinessAdapter(mBusinesses);
    mBusinessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My BusinessAdapter:

```
public class BusinessAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BusinessAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Business> mBusinesses = new ArrayList<Business>();

    // Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
    // (custom viewholder)
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextViewName;
        public TextView mTextViewDescription;
        public ImageView mImageViewLogo;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextViewName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_company_name);
            mTextViewDescription = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_company_description);
            mImageViewLogo = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView_company_logo);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public BusinessAdapter(List<Business> myBusinesses) {

        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "BusinessAdapter -> constructor");

        mBusinesses = myBusinesses;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public BusinessAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
            int viewType) {

        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "BusinessAdapter -> onCreateViewHolder()");

        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_business_list, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "BusinessAdapter -> onBindViewHolder()");

        Business item = mBusinesses.get(position);
        holder.mTextViewName.setText(item.getName());
        holder.mTextViewDescription.setText(item.getDescription());
        holder.mImageViewLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "BusinessAdapter -> getItemCount()");

        if (mBusinesses != null) {
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "mBusinesses Count: " + mBusinesses.size());
            return mBusinesses.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But I don't get the data displayed in the view. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my log,

```
07-14 21:15:35.669: D/xxx(2259): Dummy Data Inserted
07-14 21:15:35.669: D/xxx(2259): Businesses Length: 3
07-14 21:26:26.969: D/xxx(2732): BusinessAdapter -> constructor
```

I don't get any logs after this. Shouldn't `getItemCount()` in adapter should be called again?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In your `parseResponse()` you are creating a new instance of the `BusinessAdapter` class, but you aren't actually using it anywhere, so your `RecyclerView` doesn't know the new instance exists.

You either need to:

- Call `recyclerView.setAdapter(mBusinessAdapter)` again to update the RecyclerView's adapter reference to point to your new one
- Or just remove `mBusinessAdapter = new BusinessAdapter(mBusinesses);` to continue using the existing adapter. Since you haven't changed the `mBusinesses` reference, the adapter will still use that array list and should update correctly when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!  Got it.. just removed the line that creates a new instance again. Will accept your answer in 8 mins.

Comment: This did not work for me, i had to recrate teh adapter and set it again to the recylerview

Comment: I'm following your second point by creating the adapter again with new BusinessAdapter(mBusinesses). Do I have to release the old adapter in any way? Will this cause a memory leak if I just keep creating a new adapter each time?

Comment: As long as you are not statically referencing anything or otherwise holding on to references, you can just let the old reference go.

Comment: Just find position where you added or removed data from your list using `int index = list.indexOf(object)` and according to that index you can notify data using `adapter.notifyItemChanged(index)`

Comment: I created a method setData in Adapter, and passed the updated list, and then I called setAdapter(mAdapter); and it worked

Comment: Hi @Tanis.7x I am stuck with a similar problem.I have also posted a question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893288/how-do-i-refresh-a-recyclerview-in-android .I hope you would be able to help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

Try this method:

```
List<Business> mBusinesses2 = mBusinesses;
mBusinesses.clear();
mBusinesses.addAll(mBusinesses2);
//and do the notification
```

a little time consuming, but it should work.

Comment: This statement:  List<Business> mBusinesses2 = mBusinesses;  does **not** make a deep copy of the list. So you're not cloning the list - that's one thing, the second thing is I don't see how this could solve the original problem....

Comment: Actually I had a similar problem and resolved it this way:
[solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495542/notifydatasetchange-not-working-on-recyclerview/29032141#29032141)

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki Yet it does

Answer (score 16):

Just to complement the other answers as I don't think anyone mentioned this here:  `notifyDataSetChanged()` **should be executed on the main thread** (other `notify<Something>` methods of `RecyclerView.Adapter` as well, of course)

From what I gather, since you have the parsing procedures and the call to  `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the same block, either you're calling it from a worker thread, or you're doing JSON parsing on main thread (which is also a no-no as I'm sure you know). So the proper way would be:

```
protected void parseResponse(JSONArray response, String url) {
    // insert dummy data for demo
    // <yadda yadda yadda>
    mBusinessAdapter = new BusinessAdapter(mBusinesses);
    // or just use recyclerView.post() or [Fragment]getView().post()
    // instead, but make sure views haven't been destroyed while you were
    // parsing
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mBusinessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

}

*PS* Weird thing is, I don't think you get any indications about the main thread thing from either IDE or run-time logs. This is just from my personal observations: if I do call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from a worker thread, I don't get the obligatory *Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views* message or anything like that - it just fails silently (and in my case one off-main-thread call can even prevent succeeding main-thread calls from functioning properly, probably because of some kind of race condition)

Moreover, neither the [RecyclerView.Adapter api reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) nor the relevant official [dev guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) explicitly mention the main thread requirement at the moment (the moment is 2017) and none of the Android Studio lint inspection rules seem to concern this issue either.

But, [here is an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36512407/375929) of this by the author himself

Comment: Man thanks a lot! Out of all things I tried, yours worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Maximus glad I could help, mate

Comment: damn! didnt new that notifyDataset change listener need to be called from main thread, perfect, +1

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem. I just solved it with declaring `adapter` public before `onCreate` of class.

```
PostAdapter postAdapter;
```

after that

```
postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), posts);
recList.setAdapter(postAdapter);
```

at last I have called:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    // Display the size of your ArrayList
    Log.i("TAG", "Size : " + posts.size());
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

May this will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is a bit strange, but the `notifyDataSetChanged` does not really work without setting new values to adapter. So, you should do:

```
array = getNewItems();                    
((MyAdapter) mAdapter).setValues(array);  // pass the new list to adapter !!!
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your old viewmodel and set the new data to the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, force run #notifyDataSetChanged in main ui thread will fix

```
public void refresh() {
        clearSelection();
        // notifyDataSetChanged must run in main ui thread, if run in not ui thread, it will not update until manually scroll recyclerview
        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I always have this problem that I forget that the RecyclerView expects a new instance of a List each time you feed the adapter.

```
List<X> deReferenced = new ArrayList(myList);
adapter.submitList(deReferenced);
```

Having the "same" List (reference) means not declaring "new" even if the List size changes, because the changes performed to the List also propagates to other Lists (when they are simply declared as `this.localOtherList = myList`) emphasis on the keyword being "**=**", usually components that compare collections make a copy of the result after the fact and store it as "old", but not Android DiffUtil.

So, if a component of yours is giving the same List each and every time you submit it, the RecyclerView won't trigger a new layout pass.
The reason is that... AFAIR, before the DiffUtil even attempts to apply the Mayers algorithm, there is a line doing a:

```
 if (newList == mList)) {return;}
```

I am not sure how much "good practice" does de-referencing within the same system is actually defined as "good" ...
Specially since a diff algorithm is expected to have a new(revised) vs old(original) component which SHOULD in theory dereference the collection by itself after the process has ended but... who knows...?

## But wait, there is more...

doing new ArrayList() dereferences the List, BUT for some reason Oracle decided that they should make a second "ArrayList" with the same name but a different functionality.

This ArrayList is within the Arrays class.

```
/**
     * Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.  (Changes to
     * the returned list "write through" to the array.)  This method acts
     * as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in
     * combination with {@link Collection#toArray}.  The returned list is
     * serializable and implements {@link RandomAccess}.
     *
     * <p>This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size
     * list initialized to contain several elements:
     * <pre>
     *     List&lt;String&gt; stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param <T> the class of the objects in the array
     * @param a the array by which the list will be backed
     * @return a list view of the specified array
     */
    @SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
        return new ArrayList<>(a); //Here
    }
```

This write-through is funny because if you:

```
Integer[] localInts = new Integer[]{1, 2, 8};
Consumer<List<Integer>> intObserver;

public void getInts(Consumer<List<Integer>> intObserver) {
    this.intObserver = intObserver;
    dispatch();
}

private void dispatch() {
    List<Integer> myIntegers = Arrays.asList(localInts);
    intObserver.accept(myIntegers);
}
```

... later:

```
getInts(
    myInts -> {
    adapter.submitList(myInts); //myInts = [1, 2, 8]
    }
);
```

Not only does the List dispatched obeys the dereferencing on each submission, but when the `localInts` variable is altered,

```
public void set(int index, Integer value) {
    localInts[index] = value;
    dispatch(); // dispatch again
}
```

...

```
myModel.set(1, 4) // localInts = [1, 4, 8]
```

this alteration is also passed to the List WITHIN the RecyclerView, this means that on the next submission, the `(newList == mList)` will return "false" allowing the DiffUtils to trigger the Mayers algorithm, **BUT** the `areContentsTheSame(@NonNull T oldItem, @NonNull T newItem)` callback from the `ItemCallback<T>` interface will throw a "true" when reaching index 1. basically, saying "the index 1 inside RecyclerView (that was supposed to be 2 in th previous version) was always 4", and a layout pass will still not perform.

So, the way to go in this case is:

```
List<Integer> trulyDereferenced = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(localInts));
adapter.submitList(trulyDereferenced);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for those users who use reverse layout like chat list**

add this function in your adapter class

```
fun updateChatList(msgData: DataDetails) { // DataDetails is custom model class
    var tmpdata = ArrayList<DataDetails>()
    tmpdata.add(msgData)
    tmpdata.addAll(data)  //data is your data define in adapter
    data.clear()
    data.addAll(tmpdata)
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```