# Data is not inserting dynamically in RecyclerView from sqlite

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

Hello guys am trying to load data dynamically in Recyclerview here is my code :

PostAdapter.java

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Post> listData;
String rpostid, ruserid, rname, rcat, rdate, rtittle;

public PostAdapter(ArrayList<Post> postList) {
    this.listData = postList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public PostAdapter(ArrayList<Post> postList,int i) {
    this.listData = postList;
    this.notifyItemRangeInserted(getItemCount()+1,i);
}

@Override
public PostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.post_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new posts(v);
}

public class posts extends ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTittle, tvPostId, tvUseId, tvName, tvCat, tvDate;

    public posts(View v) {
        super(v);
        /* View stuf */
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    final posts holder = (posts) viewHolder;
    Post post = listData.get(position);
    rpostid = post.getPost_id();
    ruserid = post.getUser_id();
    rname = post.getUser_name();
    rcat = post.getPost_cat();
    rdate = post.getPost_time();
    rtittle = post.getPost_title();
    holder.tvPostId.setText(rpostid);
    holder.tvUseId.setText(ruserid);
    holder.tvName.setText(rname);
    holder.tvCat.setText(rcat);
    holder.tvDate.setText(rdate);
    holder.tvTittle.setText(rtittle);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listData.size();
}
```

}

Here is my code for updating data when swipeToRefresh is call

```
public void newPost(int s){
    postNew = handler.getNewPost(s);//getting data from DB
    postList.addAll(postNew);
    adapter = new PostAdapter(postNew);   
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is the code for adding data at the bottom while scrolling

```
public void oldPost(int s){
    postNew = handler.getOldPost(s);// getting data from db
    postList.addAll(postNew);
    adapter = new PostAdapter(postNew,postNew.size());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I want to make data insertion dynamically on the top of recyclerView when SwipeToRefresh is called and want to show old data at the bottom of recyclerview when scroll down. New data is inserted but not dynamically instead recyclerview refreshes and goes to its beginning.

All the thing is working fine like getting the bottom of recycleview and calling the ***oldPost()*** + Swipe to refresh to call ***newPost()***. The problem is only that data is not loading dynamically please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To notify a recycler view of a data set change you must use notifyDatasetChanged(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740557/notifydatasetchanged-not-working-on-recyclerview

Comment: I am calling notifyDatasetChanged(); see postadapter.java

Comment: Yeah but it's called in the constructor. this is another post about how to use it properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE after the edit:

you need to move your update code out of the constructor and to a normal method, the constructor "constructs" a new object instance and does not magically update anything:

```
public void InsertInPoistion(ArrayList<Post> postList,int i) {
    int begin = listData.size();
    this.listData.addAll(postList);
    int end = listData.size();
    this.notifyItemRangeInserted(begin ,end);
}
```

then call this method inside your fragment/activity:

```
mAdapter.InsertInPoistion(postNew,postNew.size());
```

mAdapter here is a reference you keep after instantiating your adapter for the first time. only create a new adapter in onCreate()

Comment: @ Ramin, In onBindViewHolder all the values are binded but to I did't show this in my code check my question, I updated the coding part.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a contentprovider and LoaderCallback. I will automatically do all that for you.

Checkout my example
https://github.com/codephillip/CarContentProvider

It might be of help

Comment: My all code is setup and i am near to make to properly working and If I'll use this example than it will take few days to understand + implementation because am new in android ......