# Android - Cannot update RecyclerView after I fetch all the Download links from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I want to fetch all the Video files from the Firebase Storage and display them in the RecyclerView. I have managed to get all the files, but I am not able to update the RecyclerView once I get all the files retrieved. Here is the code

```
 recyclerViewVideoList.setHasFixedSize(true)
 recyclerViewVideoList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
 recyclerViewVideoList.adapter = VideoListRecyclerViewAdapter(applicationContext,videoList, this)
 getVideos()

 private fun getVideos() {
    val listRef = firebaseStorage.reference.child("videos")
    listRef.listAll()
        .addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
            listResult.items.forEach { item ->
                item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    videoList.add(Video(item.name, it.toString(), "565656"))
                }
            }
           recyclerViewVideoList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Something went wrong. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43143551/13058358), but it calls the notifyDataSetChanged() multiple times. I want to avoid doing that.

Comment: please add adapter initialization code as well

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: code looks fine, try to notify VideoListRecyclerViewAdapter instead of recyclerViewVideoList.adapter. recyclerViewVideoList.adapter can be null.

Comment: put a debug point on a line where you notify data set changed and see whether you list is updated or not

Comment: @Junaid Khan, I have initialized the adapter before calling the function itself. How can it be null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more effective solution is to call the **notifyDataSetChanged()** function only for the last element of the list item.
By doing this your notifyDataSetChanged() function executed for only last element and update all the recycler view.

Change this:

```
   .addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
        listResult.items.forEach { item ->
            item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                videoList.add(Video(item.name, it.toString(), "565656"))
            }
        }
       recyclerViewVideoList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

this

```
//Declare one integer count variable var count = 0

     .addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
        listResult.items.forEach { item ->
            item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                videoList.add(Video(item.name, it.toString(), "565656"))
                count++
                if(count == listResult.items.size)
                   recyclerViewVideoList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()  
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
         .addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
            listResult.items.forEach { item ->
                item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    videoList.add(Video(item.name, it.toString(), "565656"))
                }
            }
           recyclerViewVideoList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

into this:

```
        .addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
            listResult.items.forEach { item ->
                item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    videoList.add(Video(item.name, it.toString(), "565656"))
                    recyclerViewVideoList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
```

Comment: This will work, but the adapter will get updated for each iteration of for each loop. I want the code to get all the files and then update the adapter.

Comment: The code that you are using is asynchronous, the reason why it doesn't work in your code is because the `notifyDataSetChanged()` is getting called before even retrieving the data, that's why you put it under `add()`

Comment: I get that. But can I some how manage to update the list without calling the notifyDataSetChanged() multiuple times ?

Comment: no this is the only way if you are following the mvvm pattern, you can use livedata and set the value then in the fragment/activity when you observe you can call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Do you have any link to some example / documentation that could help me with that ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects but i think its the same as adding it under `add()` in terms of updating for each iteration. Because the `observe()` method will get called whenever there are data changes in the livedata

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think the only option I have is to call notifyDataSetChanged again and again